# Must have Matplotlib installed

Tags: python, matplotlib, qiskit

I have installed matplotlib but I was still getting this error
How can I solve this error?

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [10], in <cell line: 18>()
     16 array_to_latex(psi, pretext="|\\psi\\rangle =")
     17 # Show it on a Bloch sphere
---> 18 plot_bloch_multivector(psi)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\visualization\state_visualization.py:276, in plot_bloch_multivector(state, title, figsize, rho)
    243 """Plot the Bloch sphere.
    244 
    245 Plot a sphere, axes, the Bloch vector, and its projections onto each axis.
   (...)
    273         plot_bloch_multivector(state, title="New Bloch Multivector")
    274 """
    275 if not HAS_MATPLOTLIB:
--> 276     raise ImportError('Must have Matplotlib installed. To install, run "pip install '
    277                       'matplotlib".')
    278 # Data
    279 bloch_data = _bloch_multivector_data(state)

ImportError: Must have Matplotlib installed. To install, run "pip install matplotlib".
```

Comment: Posting code or errors as images makes it harder for us to help.  Please update your question to post as plain text only, and remove the images.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a virtual environment sometime python doesn't know where to look for installed site packages, but you can correct this by setting the PYTHONPATH environment variable by following the instructions [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables). If you set the PYTHONPATH to the path you have installed matplotlib, I think this will probably fix your problem... hope it helps!

Ps.: Keep in mind that using a virtual enviroment its always the best choice to resolve that kind of problem at first place, and you only need two lines of code for doing that ;)